# Git svn: How do I define the name of the directory that clone puts the code in?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I'm running this command:

```
git svn clone https://svn.corp.company.com/svn/results -T trunk -b branches -t tags
```

And this creates a directory named "results" that it puts things in.  I don't want that to happen.  I want it to place the files directly in the directory I'm in or a directory name of my choice.  How do I do that?

I'm reading [this documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-svn.html), and I don't see anything that allows me to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a dot behind your command, like so:

```
git svn clone https://svn.corp.company.com/svn/results -T trunk -b branches -t tags .
```

Comment: Thanks.  Teach a man to fish here; where does the documentation point that out?

Comment: The git-svn manual page says: clone: Runs init and fetch. It will automatically create a directory based on the basename of the URL passed to it; **or if a second argument is passed; it will create a directory and work within that.**

Answer (score 1):

You simply add the path of the directory you want to the end of the command.